# How to deploy spring cloud microservice on Azure cloud

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am working on micro service development using Spring Cloud and Netflix Eureka. Now I want to deploy these microservices on Azure. I tried to follow this [Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/) but I am not sure that it's a best way to deploy microservices on Azure cloud.

Please suggest me what is the best way to deploy these micro service on Azure Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two options**

1. You can use Spring-Boot and push it to the docker container, as docker [recently launched](https://github.com/chanezon/azure-java-samples/blob/master/docker.md) the support for [Azure cloud.](https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/06/09/docker-on-microsoft-azure/#)
2. You can deploy through [Pivotal Cloud Foundry](http://pivotal.io/microsoft) on Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for the reply. I am trying to follow steps mentioned in  below link but I am unable to start Eureka and other micro-services. Could you please elaborate why I can not use this procedure(by adding web.config file) to deploy our Spring-boot micro services instead of this I have to use Pivotal Cloud Foundry or Docker on Azure ?

Link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/#application-configuration-examples

Comment: Hi Sunil, Can you please post your stack trace and pom.xml to investigate further?

Comment: Here is [link](https://github.com/sunilsoni/supplier-collaboration) for eureka-server. I am unable to deploy this code in Azure getting error '502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.'

Answer (score 0):

Now you can also deploy using Azure Spring Cloud.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-tutorial-prepare-app-deployment

You can still use Azure App Service, But it is better to use it for monolithic applications.

For micro-services architecture, you should go with Azure Spring-Cloud as it will manage everything for you.