# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for ip

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

Below is my bom microservice:

```
@RestController
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PLMBommsApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PLMBommsApplication.class);

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")
    public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(@PathVariable String applicationName) {
        return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody StringBuilder bom() throws URISyntaxException {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String result = null;
        LOG.info("Starting to send to Part Microservice==============>>>");
        LOG.info("Starting call====>");
        List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstance = discoveryClient.getInstances("plm-part-ms");
        ServiceInstance partInstance = serviceInstance.get(0);
        try {
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
            mvm.add("abc", "Hello Part");
            String urlString = "http://" + partInstance.getHost() + ":" + Integer.toString(partInstance.getPort())
                    + "/partPost";
            LOG.info("URL String: " + urlString);
            result = restTemplate.postForObject(urlString, mvm, String.class);
            response.append("successPost = " + result);
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            response.append("failPost = " + printException(e));
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        try {
            result = restTemplate.getForObject(partInstance.getUri(), String.class);
            response.append("successGet = " + result);
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            response.append("failGet = " + printException(e));
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        return response;
    }

    public static String printException(Throwable t) {

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        t.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        if (t instanceof StorageException) {
            if (((StorageException) t).getExtendedErrorInformation() != null) {
                System.out.println(String.format("\nError: %s",
                        ((StorageException) t).getExtendedErrorInformation().getErrorMessage()));
            }
        }
        return (String.format("Exception details:\n%s", stringWriter.toString()));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bomPost", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String bomPost(@RequestParam(value = "abc") String param1) {
        LOG.info("in plm-bom-ms post method: " + param1);
        return "return response from plm-bom-ms post method";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bomGet", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public String bomGet() {
        LOG.info("in plm-bom-ms get method");
        return "return response from plm-bom-ms get method";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(PLMBommsApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

The above microservice is trying to do rest call to another microservice, part microservice:

```
@RestController
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class PLMPartmsApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PLMPartmsApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")
    public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(@PathVariable String applicationName) {
        return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody StringBuilder part() throws URISyntaxException {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String result = null;
        LOG.info("Starting to send to BOM Microservice==============>>>");
        LOG.info("Starting call====>");
        List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstance = discoveryClient.getInstances("plm-bom-ms");
        ServiceInstance bomInstance = serviceInstance.get(0);
        try {
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
            String urlString = "http://" + bomInstance.getHost() + ":" + Integer.toString(bomInstance.getPort())
                    + "/bomPost";
            LOG.info("URL String: " + urlString);
            mvm.add("abc", "Hello BOM");
            result = restTemplate.postForObject(urlString, mvm, String.class);
            response.append("successPost = " + result);
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            response.append("failPost = " + printException(e));
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        try {
            String urlString = "http://" + bomInstance.getHost() + ":" + Integer.toString(bomInstance.getPort())
                    + "/bomGet";
            LOG.info("URL String: " + urlString);
            result = restTemplate.getForObject(urlString, String.class);
            response.append("successGet = " + result);
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            response.append("failGet = " + printException(e));
            response.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        return response;
    }

    public static String printException(Throwable t) {

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        t.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        if (t instanceof StorageException) {
            if (((StorageException) t).getExtendedErrorInformation() != null) {
                System.out.println(String.format("\nError: %s",
                        ((StorageException) t).getExtendedErrorInformation().getErrorMessage()));
            }
        }
        return (String.format("Exception details:\n%s", stringWriter.toString()));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/partPost", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String partPost(@RequestParam(value = "abc") String param1) {
        LOG.info("in plm-part-ms post method: " + param1);
        return "in plm-part-ms post method";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/partGet", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public String partGet() {
        LOG.info("in plm-part-ms get method ");
        return "in plm-part-ms get method";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(PLMPartmsApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

I get the below exception:

```
Exception details:\njava.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for 100.77.236.18\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:79)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:46)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:65)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:357)\r\n\tat com.jci.bommsplm.PLMBommsApplication.bom(PLMBommsApplication.java:83)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

Eureka, BOM and Part microservices are deployed on azure. Eureka registers both the microservices and also i can part microservice details in bom microservice by using "/service-instances/plm-part-ms", where "plm-part-ms" is the spring application name for part microservice. ANy help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Santosh, It seems that the issue was caused by some limits on Azure Webapp, such as connection attempts to local addresses and the machine's own IP will fail, etc, please see [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

According to the similar SO thread [How to deploy spring cloud microservice on Azure cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412725/how-to-deploy-spring-cloud-microservice-on-azure-cloud), Please try to use Azure Docker or Pivotal Cloud Foundry from Azure Marketplace to deploy your Spring Boot project.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new RestTemplate instead of autowiring it.